# how converting object to float in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, floating

I have a dataframe in each columns I have numbers but the type is object! how I can convert object to float?

I tried this :
`pd.to_numeric(df['Close_x'],errors='coerce')`

but the error says:

`TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series`

I tried `concatenated['Close_x'].astype(float)`

the error says:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,001.96'`

Comment: I get this error: ` 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @Sushanth no still I get errors, I have tried many ways

Comment: ``Close_x`` might be duplicate, print(concatenated.columns) & see for your self.

Comment: yes so the problem is duplicate names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers have `,` as a separator so first, you need to replace it with an empty string, then convert it to a floating-point number.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['1,001.96', '1001.98'], columns=['value'])
pd.to_numeric(df['value'].replace(',', '',regex=True))
```

or

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '')).astype(float)
```

Note: `df.apply` is slower than `pd.to_numeric` for large dataframes

Comment: they don't have